# JavaFX: Get line height of TextArea

Tags: css, javafx, textarea

I have a window/stage and a TextArea which will be resized dependent on the length of the text inside the TextArea (the text is wrapped). This means, the window is smaller, the less the text is inside the TextArea. The width of the TextArea is given. To calculate the height of the TextArea I use the length of the text, the given width of the TextArea and the line height. For example:

> double height=textwidth/agreement.getWidth()*18;

In this case the line-height is defined by a static value. But the line height have to be variable dependent on the definitions in the css-file, because the line height changes if the definition of the font size changes. Consequently I need to determine the line height of the TextArea to use it instead of using a static value. So, how can I get the line height of a TextArea?

Comment: Is your problem in removing the vertical-scroll bar from the TextArea by setting the height to a value that is enough to contain all the text with no scrolling?

Comment: No, the scrollbar doesnt matter. It can be used, if the textArea will be to large (bigger than half of screensize). If the TextArea is smaller than half the screensize it should be having the height of the text which is in it. In other case it has a height of half of the screen where a scrollbar is using within the TextArea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the exact dimensions of the text rendered in the text area, once the stage is shown:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextArea area = new TextArea("This is some random very long text");
    area.setWrapText(true);
    area.setPrefWidth(200);
    area.setMaxWidth(200);
    area.setStyle("-fx-font: 18pt Arial");
    StackPane root = new StackPane(area);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    Text t = (Text)area.lookup(".text");
    System.out.println("LayoutX "+t.getLayoutX());
    System.out.println("LayoutY "+t.getLayoutY());
    System.out.println("Width: "+t.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth());
    System.out.println("Height: "+t.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());
}
```

Based on those dimensions, you can perform your calculations.

**EDIT**

You can get the dimensions before showing the stage, but for that you need to apply CSS styling to the root and children and force a layout on the scene:

```
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    root.applyCss();
    root.layout();

    Text t = (Text)root.lookup(".text");
    System.out.println("LayoutX "+t.getLayoutX());
    System.out.println("LayoutY "+t.getLayoutY());
    System.out.println("Width: "+t.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth());
    System.out.println("Height: "+t.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());

    // Now calculations can be performed

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: This works, thanks :) Do you also know a solution if the stage is not shown? At the moment I'm using your solution and hide the stage immediately as soon as it was shown the first time (its not a good way, but it works ;)). After this I recalculate the size of the stage with the help of the height of the textArea and show that stage again.

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer with the proper way to do it

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I tried that solution but I get the error, that .applyCss() is undefined. Doesn't matter whether I apply it to a scene, StackPane, AnchorPane,...Is it possible that it is just working with JavaFX 8? I'am implementing everything in JavaFX 2. If so, I will still use your first solution ;)

Comment: Yes, you are right, `applyCss()` is new since JavaFX 8.